# How to put tablayout into toolbar and they are in the same line in android developer

Tags: android, layout, tabs, toolbar

[I want this effect.The tab is in the toolbar,not under the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3uO8.jpg)

I searched all of the website but can't find a way to do that thing.All document tells me how to add a tab under the toolbar but it's not what i want

Comment: It's the same effect as the one we see on the [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zYrUr.jpg "Lollipop Clock").  
I'm looking for the same answer and, if I find it, I promosse I'll come back here =)

Comment: if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with the answer, and it's simpler than I thougth:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            style="@style/MainTabLayout"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_toolbar"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

So there we have.
It's not the exactly same design as yours, but you just change whatever you want.
And don't forget to set your toolbar on your fragment or activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```